# Convert function from JS to PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I have a function in javascript and it works just fine, but now I need same function in PHP and it has very strange behavior. It seems to me that functions are identical, still I missed something and cannot find it.

borders, neighbors are pre-defined arrays and base is predefined string.

**Java Script**

```
function calculateAdjacent(sourceBase, direction) {
    sourceBase = sourceBase.toLowerCase();
    var lastChar = sourceBase.charAt(sourceBase.length-1);
    var type = (sourceBase.length % 2) ? 'odd' : 'even';
    var base = sourceBase.substring(0,sourceBase.length-1);
    if (BORDERS[direction][type].indexOf(lastChar)!=-1)
    {
        base = calculateAdjacent(base, direction);
    }
    return base + TABLE[NEIGHBORS[direction][type].indexOf(lastChar)];
}
```

**PHP**

($table, $neighbors, $borders are defined, they take a lot of space but I can but them in.)

```
function calculateAdjacent($sourceBase, $direction)
{
    $sourceBase = strtolower($sourceBase);
    $lastChar = $sourceBase[strlen($sourceBase) - 1];
    if (strlen($sourceBase) % 2)
    {
        $type = "odd";
    }
    else
    {
        $type = "even";
    }
    $base = substr($sourceBase, 0, strlen($sourceBase) - 1);
    if (strpos($borders[$direction][$type], $lastChar) === false)
    {
        $base = calculateAdjacent($base, $direction);
    }
    // Problem in this line, need to fix '+' to '.'
    return $base + $table[strpos($neighbors[$direction][$type], $lastChar)];
}
```

Comment: `$table` is not defined in the PHP function.

Comment: It iterates only once and returns one char where in js it returns multiple chars.

Comment: Just FYI, you can do something like this in PHP: `$type = strlen($sourceBase) % 2 ? "odd" : "even";` to condense that if statement, like you are in the JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Concatenation operator probably (depending whether your function returns string or number):

```
return $base . $table[strpos($neighbors[$direction][$type], $lastChar)];
-------------^
```

Here `.` is used for PHP replacing JS's `+` for concatenation.

Comment: Yes, it was it, I knew it was something tiny. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

The `$borders` variable is not defined (or not in scope).

**Edit:** `$neighbors` also.

Comment: It is, I cut them out since the arrays take a lot of space in code.

Comment: @Qmal Then at least leave a commented line, mentioning that.. It's an important detail.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you are using the ternary operator in JS , but not PHP, just curious to why?

```
if (strlen($sourceBase) % 2)
{
    $type = "odd";
}
else
{
    $type = "even";
}
```

can be in php

```
$type = strlen($sourceBase) % 2 ? "odd" : "even";
```